# Glade UI Python serial read loop

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm writing a python program to monitor for serial activity, and when there is serial activity, to increment a number.

When inside the while loop, no other functions will work and I can't modify the UI so it is kind of self defeating. Is there any way to do this easily?

```
i=0
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty001',9600)
while 1:
 data=ser.read();
 if data:
   i=i+1
   button.set_label(str(i))
```

edit: sorry I typed the code out too quickly and missed a few lines. basically the loop is looping forever and nothing else in the application can get done until the loop stops.

Comment: What is the result of running this, and how does it differ from the expected result?

Comment: it results in looping forever and the button label never changes. I was expecting the button label to change when data was detected

Answer (score 1):

The code as written is checking to see if /dev/tty001 can be opened.  I'm not sure if that relates to serial activity.

Do you close that serial connection later in the loop?  If not the script will open thousands of files and then die through a lack of resources (no more file descriptors).

I suggest the code is rewritten as a function, e.g.

```
def check_for_serial_activity():
   serial_activity = "some code which sets True or False"
   return serial_activity
```

You'd need to replace "some code which sets True or False" with your own logic.

You'd need to clarify your question to work out what that code should be.

You'd call the function in the main GUI loop.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this is to use another thread to wait on the comms whether serial or socket. It handles the comm and uses flags or a deque to pass the data or event back to the main loop. This way it can block without holding up the event driven part. In the main loop you can use the flag to update your button then reset it.